# Add div After 5th Post ONLY With PHP In Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have been searching the Internet for hours trying to come up with a solution. All the results are basically of the same issues of people wanting a (div) after X amount of posts and wanting the (div) to constantly repeat.

What I am looking for help with is a (div) after the 5th post, ONLY. This is for a wordpress blog, with the use of PHP.

Here is a code snippet that ads the (div) after every 5th and 15th post, but I want the (div) after the 5th post ONLY.

```
<?php if( ($wp_query->current_post % 14) == 4  ) : ?>

    <div></div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I've tried editing the code by I just can't seem to get it to show after the 5th post only. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `current_post` starts from 0, so `current_post % 4 == 0` will do it, or just `current_post == 4`

Comment: I dont' get why are you using `% 14` here, but, you should just use `current_post == 4` instead of `current_post % 4 == 0`

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error.. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':'

Answer (score 0):

`$posts->current_post` starts from 0 at first post. [WP_Query for more info](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

In order to get **only** 5th post you should compare `current_post` to the number `4`,

```
 <?php if( $wp_query->current_post == 4  ) : ?>
    <p><?php echo the_title() . ' is the 5th post';?></p>
 <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error.. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':'

Comment: unexpected `:` double dot, do you see it here `current_post == 4`?

Comment: double check your code, i think you left excess bracket at your `if` line something here `if( ($wp_query->current_post % 14) == 4  ) :`
The error message is telling you what's wrong, just read it

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it, thankyou @line88 ! It's almost 4am here and I was up all night, so forgive me.

Comment: @hellow did you read the q and a? here is the answer `current_post == 4`

Comment: Yes I did, and I think my comment is wrong now. What I really wanted to say is, that in the current state, your answer is more of a comment, because you should extend it a little bit more than one sentence.

Comment: @hellow oh, i get it. will do, thanks for getting it clear